# subset functionality in the code below what actually it is doing

Tags: gnu-make

```
bj_dir = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR),$(subst $(ROOTDIR),,$(CURDIR)))/
target  = $(obj_dir)libnovds_delivery.a

sources = \
          novds_my_delivery_service_timer.c \
          novds_my_delivery.c \
          novds_dcmd.c \
          novds_my_delivery_reply_service.c \
          novds_my_delivery_reply.c \
          novds_serial.c

objects = $(addprefix $(obj_dir),$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(sources)))
deps    = $(addprefix $(obj_dir),$(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(sources)))
```

i know the functionality of subst in makefile but in this piece code after ROOTDIR two commas are used i don't know what it will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, `subst` is not short for *subset*, it's short for *substitute*.

`$(subst $(ROOTDIR),,$(CURDIR)))` replaces every occurrence of whatever value `$(ROOTDIR)` expands to, with nothing (no text), in the value that `$(CURDIR)` expands to.  The commas separate arguments so the first comma separates `$(ROOTDIR)` from the next argument and the second comma separates the second argument (which is empty) from `$(CURDIR)`.

This is kind of a bad use of `subst`, though, because it will replace `$(ROOTDIR)` every time it appears (even multiple times) anywhere in the value (even in the middle or the end).

For things like this, where you want to remove a prefix only, it's best to use `patsubst`, as in `$(patsubst $(ROOTDIR)%,%,$(CURDIR))`.